# r pandoc problems when runing from bat file

Tags: r, pandoc

recently I have created some Rmd script wchich create and send html file to specified recipients. Script works perfect, when i run from application level (R Studio). But it doesn't work, when i run it from Task Scheduler (bat file) - log file indicates an error:

> ERROR: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found
>   (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).

I have checked pandoc version n R Studio:

> > pandoc_available()
> >     [1] TRUE
> >     pandoc_version()
> >     [1] ‘1.17.2’

Maybe application run from Task Scheduler do not use Pandoc library enclosed in R Studio, but try to find another Pandoc software instaled on my computer?

Any ideas? My operating system is Windows.

TK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rstudio uses this environment variable to find where pandoc is installed on your machine:
    `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")`

You need to add this location to system PATH